# need web hosting control panels with ruby on rails (phusion passenger + nginx) support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cpanel, plesk, webmin, kloxo

I am looking for web hosting control panel, **commercial or open source edition** which supports **ruby on rails** application deployment with **phusion passenger + nginx** support. I tried google but i could not find proper result. so guys please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **heroku** or any **vps hosting(linode)** or **amazon aws** for hosting,

Comment: i think you misunderstood my question , for more clarity visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels

Comment: I got your question sorry i misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such exists right now.
Although there are platforms designed which acts like a "cPanel" for ruby on rails app

**Heroku**
has tools https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ which functions like a control panel but it does not have a UI. everything runs on the terminal (login, restart server, add-ons/plugins management etc..)

**Engineyard**
has tools similar to heroku toolbelt but has its own UI.

personally I would chose Heroku. The community is bigger, has more tools/plugins and it runs on the terminal.